# React: How to update a component based on one property rather than all of them?

Tags: reactjs

I have a ReactJS class with the following properties: name, description, currentHp, maxHp.

The **currentHp** frequently changes, while the other properties do not.

How can I re-render the component while only passing in the new values of currentHp rather than the entire set of values?

There are other places in my app where passing in the entire set of values would mean passing dozens of strings that I know for a fact did not change (which seems like something I'd want to avoid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you should use the componentWillReceiveProps, then use an if just for the currentHp. If the currentHp has changed render the component, or update the local state to force the render.

Comment: I'm having trouble updating local state using setState. I'll ask a separate question for this after my time limit is up.